# Suggest Completion Issue in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I'm not getting the autocompletion or suggestions text while typing in Xcode 7. I have tried with the following methods, but none of them are worked for me.

1. Uninstall the Xcode and reinstall it again
2. Restarting the system
3. Clean the Code and Derived data (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
4. Deleted the cache (~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the apple guide for CompletingCode

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/CompletingCode.html

Also try disabling and enabling suggest completion .

To turn off the code completion feature, choose Xcode > Preferences and click Text Editing. In the Editing pane, deselect the option “Suggest completions while typing.” You can always invoke code completion by pressing Control–Space bar.

Thanks,

Anil

Comment: @Anil i have tried that also not working. Is there any other answer?

Comment: @iApple : Did u try now?
If yes then please restart your XCode 
Also please check the complete guide .